# What approach should I use to check friendship related information?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently working on a web application that involves user relationships, and I'd like to discuss the best practices for handling these interactions. Here's the scenario:

**The Problem:**
I have an API endpoint (/api/users/:username) that serves up a user's public profile data. In this app, users can send and accept friend requests, as well as block other users from sending future requests. The user schema in MongoDB includes a friends array to store references to other users' MongoDB IDs, and I've also set up a FriendRequest schema to track requests with statuses like
"pending," "accepted," or "denied."

**The Challenge:**
When a user visits another user's profile page, logged in or not, I want to display that user's profile information along with buttons for actions like "Add Friend," "Cancel Friend Request," "Block," and "Unblock." I'm struggling with where and how to calculate and manage these relationships efficiently.

**Possible Approaches:**

- **Calculate Relationship Information on Profile Endpoint:** Calculate relationship-related information when the profile data request is made. This involves attaching a currentUser object representing the authenticated user if there is one and then calculating fields like isFriends, isBlocked, hasBlocked, hasSentFriendRequest, etc., based on the data retrieved from MongoDB collection queries (such as searching the database for friend requests sent out). I attach these fields to the currentUser object and send it alongside the requested user profile data.
- **Separate Relationship Endpoint (/api/relationship)**: Create a separate endpoint specifically for managing relationships. This endpoint can handle checking friend requests, if either user has blocked the other, and other relationship-related information. When a user visits another user's profile, I make a separate request to this endpoint to retrieve relationship information.

I'd love to hear your insights and experiences. What approach do you think is more common or practical in situations like this? Do you have any alternative suggestions or best practices for managing user relationships effectively in web applications? Your wisdom is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If the profile page always displays the relationship data anyway, it is more efficient and convenient to make only a single request that returns all relevant data. You still can have a second `/relationship` endpoint, in particular for updates, and how you organise your code internally (such as the get-profile view calling/using the get-relationship view) is entirely up to you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.